# Why does Excel treat double spaces as a comma?

Tags: excel, vb.net, csv, outlook, export

I wrote an export to CSV file in my vb.net application, and I then exported it into Outlook.

The issue I've got, is that when the CSV file is being written, my code is checking for a comma in the current field, but while doing this, it also mistakes a double space for a comma, or space followed by 'Enter' key being pressed (for multiline textboxes)

An example would be if in the notes section of the customer, there is 4 lines of text, and one ends in a space - The user has then pressed enter to go to the next line, however the program is taking the next line of text and creating a new record for it, as it thinks it's a comma...

What is the reason for this? This means that data has to be super validated (ie checking for no double spaces etc) before it can be exported, which is far too time consuming.

Hopefully this makes sense!

This is the code:

```
Dim result As Boolean = True

Try
   Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
   Dim separator As String = ","
   Dim group As String = """"
   Dim newLine As String = Environment.NewLine

   For Each column As DataColumn In dtable.Columns
      sb.Append(wrapValue(column.ColumnName, group, separator) & separator)
   Next

   sb.Append(newLine)

For Each row As DataRow In dtable.Rows
   For Each col As DataColumn In dtable.Columns
        sb.Append(wrapValue(row(col).ToString(), group, separator) & separator)
    Next

     sb.Append(newLine)
Next
```

The code for wrapValue

```
Function wrapValue(value As String, group As String, separator As String) As String

    If value.Contains(separator) Then

        If value.Contains(group) Then
            value = value.Replace(group, group + group)
        End If

        value = group & value & group

    End If

    Return value

End Function
```

Comment: If you don't check for `If value.Contains(separator) Then` in `wrapValue` (i.e. enclose *all* fields in double-quotes) does it work? As it is, only fields with a comma in will be enclosed, which means that a newline will be naked and look like a new CSV line.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hi, that worked, thanks. Only issue is that when I tried importing it into my Outlook contacts, it imported one, then gave an error... I opened the file in Excel, saved it again (as a CSV), replacing the old file, and it worked! Any ideas why it didn't work the first time?

Comment: The easiest way would be to save the file from Excel with a different filename and use a hex editor to examine the contents of the files. As pointers to what might be important differences, it might be that there is a [byte order marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of one of them, or perhaps the newlines need to be 0x0D *or* 0x0A within entries instead of 0x0D 0x0A.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  Just checked, and they are very slightly different. The one I saved separately in Excel removes a value of 22 tat the start, as well as shortening it from 1960 lines to 1530. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that it's shortening it by 430 lines, I'd suggest it's something to do with the fact you're adding a load of "" before and after the value variable.

If it's removing a value at the start, then it will be removing a " before the first column header. As to why it's importing one record as you mentioned in the comments, I'm not entirely sure, however, I would suggest the issue lies in your `wrapValue` code.

Can you try changing

```
value = group & value & group
```

to

```
value = value
```

and see if that changes anything?