# Exported CSV won't import into Outlook until it's re-saved in Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, csv, outlook

I've got a procedure to export from Access to a CSV file, so that then it can be imported into Outlook.

However, once I tried importing it into Outlook, it fails, saying there's an MAPI error 0x80040107.

After opening the CSV file in Excel, I pressed 'Save' and saved it - It prompted me to save a CSV, so I pressed yes. I then closed it, but before closing, it again asked me to save it as a CSV, so I did - This time the save dialog came up, so I entered the same file name and extension (Customers A-F.csv), and since this file existed already, it asked me to replace it or cancel. When I pressed 'Yes' to replacing the existing file, the Excel file closed.

I now tried importing this newer version of the same file into Outlook - But this time it worked!

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I really don't understand why opening the file and then saving it as the same name/type fixes the issue?

If it helps, this is my code;

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to output this customer data to Outlook?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

  Dim sPath As String = ""

  Using ofd As New SaveFileDialog
      ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
      ofd.FilterIndex = 1
      ofd.FileName = "Customers " & range
        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            sPath = ofd.FileName & ""
        End If
  End Using

    ExportToCSV(dgvExport.DataSource, sPath)

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MsgBox("Export Successful!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "CSV Exported Successfully")

End If
```

ExportToCSV

```
 Dim result As Boolean = True

    Try
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Dim separator As String = ","
        Dim group As String = """"
        Dim newLine As String = Environment.NewLine

        For Each column As DataColumn In dtable.Columns
            sb.Append(wrapValue(column.ColumnName, group, separator) & separator)
        Next

        sb.Append(newLine)

        For Each row As DataRow In dtable.Rows
            For Each col As DataColumn In dtable.Columns
                sb.Append(wrapValue(row(col).ToString(), group, separator) & separator)
            Next

            sb.Append(newLine)
        Next

        Using fs As New StreamWriter(fileName)
            fs.Write(sb.ToString())
        End Using


    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        result = False

    End Try

    Return result
```

wrapValue

```
Function wrapValue(value As String, group As String, separator As String) As String

    If value.Contains(group) Then
        value = value.Replace(group, group + group)
    End If

    value = group & value & group

    Return value

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, but you want to export something FROM Access TO Outlook using VBA?  I'm sure you can do that, but what, exactly, are you exporting and importing?  It seems much more likely that you would go FROM Outlook TO Access.  Please give a little more background to describe exactly what you are trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has since been answered, but in a different question.

If this is a problem for anyone else, the issue is resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972236/6530111)

It's not to do with needing to be re-saved, it's do with the fact that the OP was adding "" when really, they didn't need to be/shouldn't have been.